# Why are used conditional move assembly instructions?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture

Why are still used conditional move instructions (`CMOV`) in assembly languages in certain cases? Why don't use `S{cond}` (skip instruction if **compare with zero**) ? Unlike CMOVs SKIPs don't have direct data dependencies (which is benefit for pipelining) and following instruction cen be arbitrary (not only condition move). Of course, it doesn't require flush pipelining, it just cancel write result of following instruction. The only bottleneck that I noticed can be seen on the following example:

```
     if(a > b) {
         a = b;
     }

     c = a % 2;
```

With **assembly** equivalent:

```
     ; R0 = a, R1 = b, R2 = c

     SUB R2, R0, R1     ; R2 = R0 - R1
     SLEG R2            ; if(R0 <= 0) PC++     | Skip If Less or Equal Zero
     CP R0, R1          ; R0 = R1
    *AND R2, R0, =1     ; R2 = R0 & 0x01
```

*** Critical execution.** Processor must wait for result of `CP` instruction, because of `R0` as operand in `AND` instruction. On the other side, this is common situation in modern CPU and is effectively solved, so I think degradation of performance wouldn't be so high as it is in the case of conditional move. Anyway, where is predictable conditional jump possible, use it.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Can you please edit the architecture you are talking about into your question? I don't see a skip instruction for i386.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I think that x86 doesn't use this instruction. Generally I know only about PICs. And my question is why this instructions aren't regularly used in modern CPUs?

Comment: @NikNovák it's up to the instruction set designer which instructions they choose to include based upon what operations they choose should be easier to write. One could just as well ask why a PIC doesn't have the x86 `rep` instruction. Conditional moves, `rep`, and many other instructions are not *essential* (their capability can be implemented using other combinations of existing instructions).

Comment: Note that a short forward branch can be interpreted as a request for predication. IBM implemented such dynamic hammock predication in POWER8 for single instruction conditional branch-overs for a significant subset of instructions.

Answer (score 1):

`SLEG R2` is a conditional-branch forward by one instruction.  It can be implemented with either a data dependency (effectively make the next instruction predicated) or branch prediction (treat the same as any other conditional branch).

Note that the result of the comparison counts as "data", so `cmov` has 3 inputs: dest, src, and flags.  Similarly, predicating an instruction with a skip adds the skip's control input to the data dependencies of the other instruction.

You have to choose one or the other.  I think the correct way to say what I think you're trying to say is that usually the data-dependency check doesn't find anything that it has to wait for.  That's going to be true less often in a 4-wide out-of-order design like modern x86 chips, because the window for data dependencies to matter is much bigger.  There are many more instructions in flight, and any independent dependency chains can run in parallel.

A skip instruction is certainly more powerful than x86's clunky `cmov`.  Since `cmov` can't take immediate operands, it often requires extra instructions to put a constant in another register as a source.

Paul Clayton's comment is interesting: POWER8 special-cases conditional forward-by-1-insn branches to handle them as data dependencies instead of control dependencies.  That sounds like it should be exactly the same as a PIC skip instruction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, you want to say me that conditional branch on POWER8 by 1 instruction (or branch distance depends on number of implemented pipeline levels?) is executed with only discard result writes that CPU jumps over? If I understand it right, at the end of pipeline (when results are writed into register/memory) must be some form of reorder buffer to get instruction back to their original order, isn't it so? Or POWER8 doesn't use out-of-order exectuion?

Comment: @NikNovák: If I understand Paul's comment correctly, they yes, POWER8 treats forward branches by 1 insn as a predicate for the next insn.  IDK if it still uses an execution unit for the instruction when the predicate turns out to be false, but that sounds likely.  And yes, most OOO CPUs use a Re-Order Buffer (ROB) to track insns from the first OOO pipeline stage (issue) to the last (retirement).  This allows in-order retirement to support precise exceptions.